# How to save file in hadoop with python

Tags: python, hadoop, hadoopy

I am trying to save file in Hadoop with python 2.7. I searched on the internet. I got some code to save a file in Hadoop but it is taking the entire folder while saving (total files in the folder are saving in Hadoop). But I need to save a specific file.

Here is the link to save a folder in Hadoop:
http://www.hadoopy.com/en/latest/tutorial.html#putting-data-on-hdfs

Now what I need is save a particular file in Hadoop like `abc.txt`.

Here is my code:

```
import hadoopy
hdfs_path = 'hdfs://192.168.x.xxx:xxxx/video/py5'
def main():
   local_path = open('abc.txt').read()
   hadoopy.writetb(hdfs_path, local_path)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here i am getting `need more than one value to unpack`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hadoopy.writetb` seems to expects an iterable of two-values as its second argument. Try:

```
hadoopy.writetb(hdfs_path, [("abc.txt", open("abc.txt").read())])
```

Comment: now i am getting `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Answer (score 0):

http://www.hadoopy.com/en/latest/api.html?highlight=hadoopy.writetb#hadoopy.writetb

writedb requires second arg as kvs – Iterator of (key, value)

As per the link you have given, you have forgot to copy the function `read_local_dir` in your code.